# What is the function of /3rdmodemnvm and /3rdmodemnvmbkp partition in android?

Tags: android

For a smartphone with android, through `adb` shell mount, we can find the partitions of `/3rdmodemnvm` and `/3rdmodemnvmbkp`, see as follow:

```
/dev/block/platform/hi_mci.0/by-name/3rdmodemnvm /3rdmodemnvm ext4 rw,context=u:object_r:radio_data_file:s0,nosuid,nodev,noatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/hi_mci.0/by-name/3rdmodemnvmbkp /3rdmodemnvmbkp ext4 rw,context=u:object_r:radio_data_file:s0,nosuid,nodev,noatime,data=ordered 0 0
```

What is the function of `/3rdmodemnvm` and `/3rdmodemnvmbkp` partition and what is the path of relevant code in android source code?

Answer (score 0):

There are part of the system image for modem of the phone, and the source code are not included in AOSP. You can not get it.